# Splide carousel block - innerBlocks not selectable after innerBlocks change

Tags: block-editor

I've built a carousel block using the [Splide library](http://splidejs.com/), which mostly works great. The options are reactive and that side of things works fine.

However I have an issue when modifying `innerBlocks` (add/remove/reordering) - the slides are no longer selectable until I refresh the browser.

I'm unsure if I've done something wrong, or if this is an issue with Splide and its refresh method. Removing [the code that handles refreshing the carousel](https://github.com/eighteen73/pulsar-blocks/blob/feature/vanilla-splide/src/carousel/edit.js#L154-L167) on `innerBlocks` change does fix the selection issue, but the carousel doesn't behave correctly as Splide is unaware of the updated slides.

Any input or suggestions would be most welcome!

- [Video showing the selection issue](https://share.cleanshot.com/TRP34bFj)
- [Code repo](https://github.com/eighteen73/pulsar-blocks/tree/feature/vanilla-splide)